# Removing rows from groups in a dataframe that have a minimum value in a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set in a csv file. I have imported it using pandas as a dataframe. I then order my data from smallest to largest based on the column which I have named Vf.

From here what my code is trying to do:
Group the sorted dataframe (DF) into groups of 11.
Calculate the difference between the corresponding min and max values in each group.
Iterate through each group and check to see if the difference between the min and max value of any of the groups is greater than 0.2.
If this condition is met for any of the groups, I want the code to remove the row of data containing the minimum value of that group from the orginal dataframe.
Then sort and group the dataframe again, minus that row.
Iterate through each group again, checking the differences between the min and max values.
It should continue to do this until it has gone through each group and found that none of them have a difference between the min and max values greater than 0.2.

Right now my code does this as far as I can tell. But it does not stop when I want it to, ie when all of the groups have a difference between the min and max values of less than 0.2, it does not stop. Also, at this point it actually seems to add rows back into the original dataframe.

Here is the code. Note that I have set it to only go through the first 2 groups in my data. Also note that the lines in my for loop asking it to print statements and the shape of the sorted dataframe. This is all to provide info for debugging purposes.

```
def celling():
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Data = input("Name of File: ")
DF = pd.read_csv("Y:\CHRIS\{}.csv".format(Data), skiprows = 20, names = ["Serial","Bin","Ir","Vf"])

def sort(Data):
    SortedDF = Data.sort_values(by='Vf')
    GroupedDF = SortedDF.groupby(np.arange(len(SortedDF))//11)
    GroupMax = GroupedDF["Vf"].max()
    GroupMin = GroupedDF["Vf"].min()
    GroupDiff = GroupMax - GroupMin
    GroupMinIndices = GroupedDF["Vf"].idxmin()
#sort(DF)
    for i in range(2):

        if GroupDiff[i] > 0.2:
            DF = Data[Data.index != GroupMinIndices[i]]
            print("Group {} was bad.".format(i))
            print(SortedDF.shape)
            sort(DF)
        else:
            print("Group {} is good.".format(i))
        print(SortedDF.shape)
sort(DF)
```

Here is a sample of what the original dataframe looks like:

```
        Serial  Bin       Ir     Vf
    0        1  1.0  0.00161  170.7
    1        2  1.0  0.00157  173.3
    2        3  1.0  0.00169  171.0
    3        4  1.0  0.00145  172.7
    4        5  1.0  0.00170  171.4
    5        6  1.0  0.00160  172.6
    6        7  1.0  0.00180  172.4
    7        8  1.0  0.00169  172.1
    8        9  1.0  0.00147  170.9
    9       10  1.0  0.00151  172.3
    10      11  1.0  0.00142  171.8
    11      12  1.0  0.00168  171.5
```

Here is a sample of the dataframe sorted by Vf:

```
    Serial  Bin       Ir     Vf
477    478  1.0  0.00180  170.0
359    360  1.0  0.00139  170.1
247    248  1.0  0.00197  170.1
575    576  1.0  0.00159  170.2
267    268  1.0  0.00178  170.2
178    179  1.0  0.00277  170.3
82      83  1.0  0.00145  170.3
574    575  1.0  0.00162  170.3
97      98  1.0  0.00190  170.3
399    400  1.0  0.00172  170.4
21      22  1.0  0.00166  170.4
67      68  1.0  0.00176  170.5
103    104  1.0  0.00154  170.5
553    554  1.0  0.00169  170.5
533    534  1.0  0.00167  170.5
177    178  1.0  0.00160  170.5
35      36  1.0  0.00150  170.5
186    187  1.0  0.00165  170.5
363    364  1.0  0.00172  170.6
487    488  1.0  0.00159  170.6
```

So ideally what the code should do here is check the first 11 lines of this sample, notice that the difference between the biggest and smallest values in that 11 is greater than 0.2, and remove the row with the minimum value from that first 11, in this case that would be the row with Serial no. 478. Then it should regroup the data, where rows 2-12 in the sample above would now constitute the first group of 11. It should then notice that the min/max difference is still greater than 0.2 and start all over again. Below should be the first group of 11 from the above sample after the code is done

```
178    179  1.0  0.00277  170.3
82      83  1.0  0.00145  170.3
574    575  1.0  0.00162  170.3
97      98  1.0  0.00190  170.3
399    400  1.0  0.00172  170.4
21      22  1.0  0.00166  170.4
67      68  1.0  0.00176  170.5
103    104  1.0  0.00154  170.5
553    554  1.0  0.00169  170.5
533    534  1.0  0.00167  170.5
177    178  1.0  0.00160  170.5
```

And here is the result of my code as it currently stands:

```
Group 0 was bad.
(643, 4)
Group 0 was bad.
(642, 4)
Group 0 was bad.
(641, 4)
Group 0 was bad.
(640, 4)
Group 0 was bad.
(639, 4)
Group 0 is good.
(638, 4)
Group 1 was bad.
(638, 4)
Group 0 is good.
(637, 4)
Group 1 was bad.
(637, 4)
Group 0 is good.
(636, 4)
Group 1 was bad.
(636, 4)
Group 0 is good.
(635, 4)
Group 1 was bad.
(635, 4)
Group 0 is good.
(634, 4)
Group 1 was bad.
(634, 4)
Group 0 is good.
(633, 4)
Group 1 is good.
(633, 4)
(634, 4)
(635, 4)
(636, 4)
(637, 4)
(638, 4)
(639, 4)
Group 1 is good.
(639, 4)
(640, 4)
Group 1 is good.
(640, 4)
(641, 4)
Group 1 is good.
(641, 4)
(642, 4)
Group 1 is good.
(642, 4)
(643, 4)
Group 1 is good.
(643, 4)
(643, 4)
```

Notice how it keeps removing rows when it reads that Group 0 has a difference between max and min that is greater than 0.2. Then it moves on to Group 1. When it reads that the max/min difference in Group 1 is greater than 0.2, it removes the row and goes back to the start of the `for` loop (I know this is not very efficient). However, notice that it should theoretically stop as soon as it reads than Group 0 is good and then that Group 1 is good, but it doesnt. And notice that after it reads they are both good, it seems to start adding rows back into the  dataframe.

If anyone could explain why my code is doing this, or explain what my code is doing, if it's not doing that, it would be greatly appreciated. Note, I'm new to python, so be kind! :)

Comment: could you add the expected output given the sample data as well.

Comment: @ Haleemur Ali Done. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky problem, so lets start by restating it.

1. **sort** the data using the column `Vf`
2. **group** successive 11 rows & find first group where the min-max spread exceeds 0.2.
3. **split** the data in two parts starting at this group, the first part will be the *good* part, and the second part will be *bad* and require rows to be removed from its start.
4. **remove** rows from the start of the *bad* part, until the spread between the `Vf` and `Vf.shift(-10)` doesn't exceed 0.2
5. repeat the steps (group-split-remove) until a split has an empty bad part
6. join all the good parts to get the final result
7. (optional) assign a group id to the final result

create the sample sorted data frame:

```
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO("""    Serial  Bin       Ir     Vf
477    478  1.0  0.00180  170.0
359    360  1.0  0.00139  170.1
247    248  1.0  0.00197  170.1
575    576  1.0  0.00159  170.2
267    268  1.0  0.00178  170.2
178    179  1.0  0.00277  170.3
82      83  1.0  0.00145  170.3
574    575  1.0  0.00162  170.3
97      98  1.0  0.00190  170.3
399    400  1.0  0.00172  170.4
21      22  1.0  0.00166  170.4
67      68  1.0  0.00176  170.5
103    104  1.0  0.00154  170.5
553    554  1.0  0.00169  170.5
533    534  1.0  0.00167  170.5
177    178  1.0  0.00160  170.5
35      36  1.0  0.00150  170.5
186    187  1.0  0.00165  170.5
363    364  1.0  0.00172  170.6
487    488  1.0  0.00159  170.6"""), sep='\s+')
```

Here are the helper functions:

```
def grouper(frame):
    return np.arange(len(frame)) // 11

def remove(frame): 
    return (
        (frame.Vf.shift(-10).fillna(frame.Vf.max()) - frame.Vf) < 0.2
    ).cumsum() > 0

def split_df(frame): 
    return frame.groupby(
        grouper(frame)
    ).Vf.transform(
        lambda x: (x.max() - x.min()) > 0.2
    ).cumsum() > 0
```

`column.cumsum() > 0` where column is has a boolean type filters all rows after  the first true value is encountered including the row which is true.

The following function implements the above recursive logic (with the help of some helper functions defined above)

```
def group_split_remove(frame):
    temp = frame[split_df(frame)]
    if len(temp) == 0:
        return frame
    return pd.concat([frame[~split_df(frame)], group_split_remove(temp[remove(temp)])])
```

*Now, recursion in python isn't always the best strategy, so, if the above isn't fast enough or hits the max recursion depth, reformulate it as a while loop. But, I believe the recursive formulation is the more readable in this case*

with your sample (sorted) data, `group_split_remove(df)` returns the following data frame:

```
     Serial  Bin       Ir     Vf
178     179  1.0  0.00277  170.3
82       83  1.0  0.00145  170.3
574     575  1.0  0.00162  170.3
97       98  1.0  0.00190  170.3
399     400  1.0  0.00172  170.4
21       22  1.0  0.00166  170.4
67       68  1.0  0.00176  170.5
103     104  1.0  0.00154  170.5
553     554  1.0  0.00169  170.5
533     534  1.0  0.00167  170.5
177     178  1.0  0.00160  170.5
35       36  1.0  0.00150  170.5
186     187  1.0  0.00165  170.5
363     364  1.0  0.00172  170.6
487     488  1.0  0.00159  170.6
```

As you can see, the first 11 rows match your expected output exactly.

The final optional step would be to assign a group_id, which can be done as follows:

```
res['group_id'] = grouper(res)
```

Comment: I do not get this output. Can you post the complete code that you wrote to get that output please. As I said I'm new at Python so I've probably not executed your code properly. Also sorry for the delay in replying, I appreciate your help very much. I have just not had much time to  look at this.

Comment: Could you also explain what the `.cumsum() > 0` is doing in both `split_df` and `remove` please

Comment: Lastly, if you could point out any problems with my original code for my own learning purposes, that would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: see updated answer for full code. execute the blocks in order which they appear in the answer to get the output that i got. your code doesn't implement logic to remove any rows from the _bad_ groups, nor does it concatenate the good groups with the fixed bad ones recursively.